# CakePHP not saving entries properly

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to copy multiple rows from one table to another but it's only saving the last entry that I select. When I print the array of data everything displays. The table that I'm copying to does not have auto_increment set and that was my guess as to why, so now I'm puzzled.

```
foreach($this->request->data['Order']['archive_value'] as $orderid){
    $data = $this->Order->query("select * from orders where orderid = '$orderid'");
    $newdata = array(
        'ArchivedOrder' => array(
                'orderid' => $data[0]['orders']['orderid'],
                'id' => $data[0]['orders']['id'],
                'order_status' => $data[0]['orders']['order_status'],
                'email' => $data[0]['orders']['email'],
                'total' => $data[0]['orders']['total'],
                'fullName' => $data[0]['orders']['fullName'],
                'address' => $data[0]['orders']['address'],
                'city' => $data[0]['orders']['city'],
                'state' => $data[0]['orders']['state'],
                'zip' => $data[0]['orders']['zip'],
                'created' => $data[0]['orders']['created'],
                'modified' => $data[0]['orders']['modified']  
        ));
        print_r($newdata); //this shows every entry that I look up, but it's not saving them properly
        $this->loadModel('ArchivedOrder');
        $this->ArchivedOrder->save($newdata);
        ///$this->Order->query("delete from orders where orderid = '$orderid'");
}
```

When I dump the table structure from PHPMyAdmin this is what shows

```
CREATE TABLE `archived_orders` (
  `orderid` int(10) default NULL,
  `id` int(10) default NULL,
  `order_status` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `total` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `fullName` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `zip` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `modified` datetime default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the CakePHP book [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array):

> When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call create().

Also probably not a good idea to do the `loadModel` within the foreach loop.

```
// load the model

// foreach loop

    // build the data
    $this->ArchivedOrder->create();
    $this->ArchivedOrder->save($newdata);

    //...
```

Comment: Didn't work. I ended up just using $this->ArchivedOrder->query("insert into...") to get it to work.

Comment: @user1443519 - don't use "insert into..." learn to use Cake the correct way first.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with that code

- Don't use query()... SQL injection ahead, your code is insecure and you lose the database abstraction. Use find().
- Not an issue but... print_r - there is debug() by CakePHP, it's a lot better than a plain print_r
- Don't use save(), use saveAll(), read [that page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html). No need to save the data in a loop
- 90% of that code should go into the model not in a controller

Comment: Can you specify what should go in the model? It's not very helpful just saying "90% of it."

Answer (score 0):

Granted your under the OrdersController

```
$newdata = array();
foreach($this->request->data['Order']['archive_value'] as $orderid){
    $data = $this->Order->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('orderid'=>$orderid)));
    if(count($data) > 0){
    $newdata[] = array(
        'ArchivedOrder' => array(
                'orderid' => $data[0]['Order']['orderid'],
                'id' => $data[0]['Order']['id'],
                'order_status' => $data[0]['Order']['order_status'],
                'email' => $data[0]['Order']['email'],
                'total' => $data[0]['Order']['total'],
                'fullName' => $data[0]['Order']['fullName'],
                'address' => $data[0]['Order']['address'],
                'city' => $data[0]['Order']['city'],
                'state' => $data[0]['Order']['state'],
                'zip' => $data[0]['Order']['zip'],
                'created' => $data[0]['Order']['created'],
                'modified' => $data[0]['Order']['modified']  
        ));
     }


}
if(count($newdata) > 0){
      $this->loadModel('ArchivedOrder');
      print_r($newdata); //this shows every entry that I look up, but it's not saving them properly
      foreach($newdata as $order):
         $this->ArchivedOrder->id = $order['ArchivedOrder']['id'];
          if($this->ArchivedOrder->exists()){
               echo 'Entered Already';
          }else{
               $this->ArchivedOrder->create();
               if($this->ArchivedOrder->save($order)){

               }else{echo 'error'; return false;}
          }
      endforeach;
}
unset($newdata);
```